# How to import an excel worksheet as a whole and save in Mysql database using python

Tags: python, mysql, excel, openpyxl, pymysql

I have an excel file(.xlsx) with 45 columns with more than a 1000 rows. I want to take all the data and store it in MySQL database using Python 3.5.

What have I done:-

I have used openpyxl for store the values in python lists like these and then store in database.

```
import pymysql
import openpyxl

source_excel=input('Enter the source excel file name-> ')
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(source_excel)
sheet=wb.active

strt=int(input('Enter starting range-> '))
end=int(input('Enter ending range-> '))

name=[]

for q in range(strt,end):
    a=q,sheet.cell(row=q,column=1).value
    name.append(a)
```

So the same way above last 3 line code, I use it 45 times and then feed into database by changing the column numbers.

Is there any way where all the data of an excel file can be fetched as a bulk and stored in Mysql?

Also, if possible please help me to how to export a MySQL table as an excel file too. Thanks!